# incorporate window.location.hash change with .cycle script

Tags: jquery, hash, cycle

can someone please help with the window.location.hash and the .cycle script. I've been trying for weeks now and i can not do it, i'm learning javascript part time and i'm no where near capable of completing this without some help.

Here's the html code i have

```
<div id="home_slide" class="slide">
  <li class="header"><a href="#" class="goToSlide" data-jim="#about_us_slide">About us</a></li>
  <li class="header"><a href="#" class="goToSlide" data-jim="#contact_us_slide">Contact us</a></li>
  <li id="back"><a href="#" class="prev_demo" data-jim="#home_slide">Home</a></li>
</div>

<div id="about_us_slide" class="slide">
  <li class="header"><a href="#" class="goToSlide" data-jim="#about_us_slide">About us</a></li>
  <li class="header"><a href="#" class="goToSlide" data-jim="#contact_us_slide">Contact us</a></li>
  <li id="back"><a href="#" class="gohome" data-jim="#home_slide">Home</a></li>
</div>

<div id="contact_us_slide" class="slide">
  <li class="header"><a href="#" class="goToSlide" data-jim="#about_us_slide">About us</a></li>
  <li class="header"><a href="#" class="goToSlide" data-jim="#contact_us_slide">Contact us</a></li>
  <li id="back"><a href="#" class="gohome" data-jim="#home_slide">Home</a></li>
</div>
```

​

Heres the CSS code i have

```
<style type='text/css'>
#container {
width: 320px;
height: 417px;

}
#nav li {
float: left;
}
#nav li a {
display: block;
border: 1px solid #333;
background: #eee;
}
#slide_containers {
clear: both;
border: 1px solid #333;
background: #eee;
}
.slide {
width: 100%;
}
#about_us_slide {
background: #cea;
width: 320px;
height: 417px;
}
#contact_us_slide {
background: #fea;
width: 320px;
height: 417px;
}

</style>
```

and finally here is the javascript code i have
    //

```
$('.goToSlide').click(function(e) { 
// Bind click event to all elements with the class goToSlide
e.preventDefault();
var selector = $(this).data('jim'); // Get the data-slide attribute value
//console.log(selector, $(selector), $(selector).index()); // DEBUG
var slideIndex = $(selector).index(); // Get the index of the slide element
$('#slide_containers').cycle(slideIndex); // Cycle to slide by index
});});
//]]>  
</script>
```

Here's also a jsfiddle of the code working
http://jsfiddle.net/mYmrx/16/

What i'm trying to do is have my domain name i.e. www.domain.com#about_us or even better would be www.domain.com/about_us

Please can someone help me, i am going crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close. You can set window.location.hash to your 'selector' variable to get pretty much what you are asking for. You can even do it after the animation completes using promise and done. Here is an example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slide_containers').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft',
        speed: 'fast',
        timeout: 0,
        prev: ".prev_demo",
    });

    // Bind click event to all elements with the class goToSlide
    $('.goToSlide').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the data-slide attribute value
        var selector = $(this).data('jim');
        // Get the index of the slide element
        var slideIndex = $(selector).index();
        $('#slide_containers').cycle(slideIndex);
        // wait for animation to complete
        var promise = $('.slide').promise();
        promise.done(function() {
            // set hash
            window.location.hash = selector;
        });
    });

    //Grab hash off URL (default to first tab) and update
    $(window).bind("hashchange", function(e) {
        var anchor = $(location.hash);
        if (anchor.length === 0) {
            $('#slide_containers').cycle(0);
        }
        var slideIndex = $(anchor).index();
        $('#slide_containers').cycle(slideIndex);
    });
});​
```

​Here is the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/AHATV/8/

Here you can see the JSFiddle in action (with the updated hash locations): http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/AHATV/8/show/

Comment: #Gary.S Hi Gary, Thank you so much for that, I have been struggling for ages with this, at least now i can play about with it more and start understanding it better. I have another issue now though, the reason why i wanted the hashtags was so i could use the back button on the browser and also be able to type the url and go directly to that slide, but with this script it won't let me, i just assumed once the url had changed it would allow me to do it. Is there any chance you can help me out a little more, i have a feeling i'll still be here in a few weeks time with the same issue if not lol

Comment: @Dan I am glad i have been able to help, supporting the back button is actually fairly simple. We just need to watch the 'hashchange' event on the window. I have updated the code sample with an example of this.

Comment: you are one in a million thank you, it works perfectly, your gonna hate me now but i have one other question, how do you get the home button to go back a page? i.e. like clicking the browser back button

Comment: @Dan Getting a link to do the 'back' functionality in javascript is pretty simple (just call window.history.back()). http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/AHATV/14/ That said, you may want to hide that when back doesn't make sense (home slide) otherwise they can end up going back to whatever page they were at before. That would look like this - http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/AHATV/15/

Comment: @Dan As an aside, add show to the end of the links to see full page implementation.

Comment: Thanks again buddy and i never knew about that show trick, i wondered how you got it to do that before, that will help in the future. Again thanks for your help.